# White space outside the html

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a simple div which is supposed to be at the centre of the screen. The same code works in Chrome, Firefox but a white space is generated around the html in IE11 and Microsoft Edge.

Please provide any workarounds other than setting the overflow to hidden. I have content which might overflow vertically.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayi34.png

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding the box-sizing on `*` : https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: @Riskbreaker Does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flexbox, here is an example that I tested in IE11 so it should work for all your supported browsers. I added a margin for the max size so the red box doesn't take up the entire screen, you can remove that if you don't care about that. I also converted your height and width into min-height and min-width in case you wanted the default smallest size.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you handle if the container were to be an image and you have to position a div at the center

Comment: That doesn't sound like a great idea, browsers aren't great at image resizing so what happens when the window is too small to display the full image? what happens if the window is too big and there is a bunch of whitespace around the image? What you could do is set the background color of the container div to black and then set the background image of the container to be the image you would like to display but that wont get around the issues I pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you provided doesn't reproduce the issue. It only shows the red `div`. Do you want the inner red `div` in the center of the outside blue `div`? I make a demo and it works in IE 11 and Edge, you could check it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```